# How to open new window on button in click in java script

Tags: javascript, php, html

When i click on button to open new window in java script then open new window but in URL automatically append my server name. how to remove this error. code given below.

Html code:

```
<input class="cssButton button_buy_now" type="submit" name="live_chat" id="live_chat" value="Get Answer"></input>
```

java script code:

```
$('#live_chat').click(function() {
    return window.open("www.helloexperts.com/index.php?main_page=filerange_chat&ex=1");
}):
```

but when new window open automatically append localhost in start like

```
locahost/www.helloexpert.com
```

why append localhost in start please help me:

Comment: put `http://` infront of the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the protocol (`http://`).

```
$('#live_chat').click(function() {

return window.open("http://www.helloexperts.com/index.php?main_page=filerange_chat&ex=1");
// Change ----------^^^^^^^

}):
```

Otherwise, it's a relative link.

Answer (score 3):

Append the protocol specifier `http://` to your url.

Comment: this must be a comment!

Comment: @Ashish why it should be comment, since that is the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should use "http://www.helloexperts.com/index.php?main_page=filerange_chat&ex=1" in the open function

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win() 
{
window.open("url");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return not required..

Try this:

```
$('#live_chat').click(function() {

window.open('sample.html','_blank','width=200,height=300');

}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#live_chat').click(function() {
    window.location.href="www.helloexperts.com/index.php?main_page=filerange_chat&ex=1";
});
```